# Does wikipedia use different methods to compute the hash part of an image path?

Tags: wikipedia

I'm using dbpedia's extraction_framework(ImageExtractor#getImageUrl) to
get the url of an image(the md5 of the first two chars)

```
   val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
   val messageDigest = md.digest(fileName.getBytes)
   val md5 = (new BigInteger(1, messageDigest)).toString(16)

   val hash1 = md5.substring(0, 1)
   val hash2 = md5.substring(0, 2);

   val urlPart = hash1 + "/" + hash2 + "/" + fileName
```

Most of the time, the function works correctly but on a few cases, it
is incorrect:

For "Stewie_Griffin.png", I get 2/26/Stewie_Griffin.png but the real
one is 0/02/Stewie_Griffin.png

The source file info is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Stewie_Griffin.png
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Stewie_Griffin.png

Any ideas why the hashing scheme doesn't work sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OQ's response to your question on the MediaWiki API mailing list](http://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/mediawiki-api/2011-December/002446.html) seems to be right:

> ```
> val md5 = (new BigInteger(1, messageDigest)).toString(16)
> ```
>
> It's eating the leading zero when you're converting it to a BigInt.
> Not sure why, when AFAIK MessageDigest provides provides a toString method()

Comment: Thanks, here's a fix when the leading zero is being eaten:     val md5 = if (result.length % 2 != 0) "0" + result else result

Comment: I recommend using org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils#md5Hex instead of manually computing it

Comment: @tommy chheng your fix will not work correctly if the md5 has several leadings `0`

Comment: Yes, i ran into that problem, relying on apache's DigestUtils#md5Hex instead of my hack fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize: to compute a path to Wikipedia image you need to use org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils#md5Hex:

```
String md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(image);
System.out.println(md5.substring(0, 1) + "/" + md5.substring(0, 2) + "/" + image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation, in JavaScript, for retrieving the absolute path of image files.

```js
const imgGroups = [
  // Dots
  ['MJt1-.svg', 'MJt2-.svg', 'MJt3-.svg', 'MJt4-.svg', 'MJt5-.svg', 'MJt6-.svg', 'MJt7-.svg', 'MJt8-.svg', 'MJt9-.svg'],
  // Bamboo
  ['MJs1-.svg', 'MJs2-.svg', 'MJs3-.svg', 'MJs4-.svg', 'MJs5-.svg', 'MJs6-.svg', 'MJs7-.svg', 'MJs8-.svg', 'MJs9-.svg'],
  // Characters
  ['MJw1-.svg', 'MJw2-.svg', 'MJw3-.svg', 'MJw4-.svg', 'MJw5-.svg', 'MJw6-.svg', 'MJw7-.svg', 'MJw8-.svg', 'MJw9-.svg'],
  // Honors
  ['MJf1-.svg', 'MJf2-.svg', 'MJf3-.svg', 'MJf4-.svg', 'MJd1-.svg', 'MJd2-.svg', 'MJd3-.svg'],
  // Bonus
  ['MJh5-.svg', 'MJh6-.svg', 'MJh7-.svg', 'MJh8-.svg', 'MJh1-.svg', 'MJh2-.svg', 'MJh3-.svg', 'MJh4-.svg']
];

const BASE_URL = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons';

const getAbsolutePath = (filename, baseUrl = BASE_URL) => {
  const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(filename.replace(/ /g, '_')).toString();
  return `${baseUrl}/${hash[0]}/${hash.substring(0, 2)}/${filename}`;
};

const groups = imgGroups.map(group =>
  group.map(filename => getAbsolutePath(filename)));

for (let group of groups) {
  for (let absolutePath of group) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = absolutePath;
    img.width = 32;
    document.body.append(img);
  }
  document.body.append(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/core.min.js" integrity="sha512-t8vdA86yKUE154D1VlNn78JbDkjv3HxdK/0MJDMBUXUjshuzRgET0ERp/0MAgYS+8YD9YmFwnz6+FWLz1gRZaw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/md5.min.js" integrity="sha512-3sGbaDyhjGb+yxqvJKi/gl5zL4J7P5Yh4GXzq+E9puzlmVkIctjf4yP6LfijOUvtoBI3p9pLKia9crHsgYDTUQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```