# How to construct full URL from Wikipedia [[File:...]] tag in wikimedia markup?

Tags: wikipedia, wikimedia

What logic does Wikipedia use to generate the full URL for images in articles, given the `[[File:...]]` tag in the wikimedia markup, or the infobox `|image=...` line?

The url seems to always start with `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/`, followed by two url segments that do not seem to be predictable, plus the image name which can be predicted from the tag.

For example,

```
[[File:Michael Jordan UNC Jersey cropped.jpg|thumb|left|Michael Jordan's jersey in the rafters of The [[Dean Smith Center]]]]
```

yields:

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Michael_Jordan_UNC_Jersey_cropped.jpg/220px-Michael_Jordan_UNC_Jersey_cropped.jpg
```

Is there any way to programatically determine the `/6/6a` part of the url, or is this a lookup on a Wikipedia server?

Another example, in the Infobox:

```
|image = Jordan Lipofsky.jpg
```

yields:

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Jordan_Lipofsky.jpg
```

Can the `/b/b3` portion of the URL be predicted?

Thanks!

Comment: Programatically from where? An external application? MediaWiki extension? A JavaScript script running on Wikipedia?

Comment: The software behind Wikipedia is called [MediaWiki](https://mediawiki.org/); there is a configuration variable called [`$wgHashedUploadDirectory`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHashedUploadDirectory) which is set to true on Wikimedia Wikis with uploads enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's generated from an MD5 hash. Something like the below in Scala will work -- although I'm not sure how to predict whether it's in /commons or in /en.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
def getImageUrl(fileName: String, rootUrl: String): String = {

    val messageDigest = DigestUtils.md5Hex(fileName.replace(" ", "_"))
    val md5 = messageDigest

    val hash1 = md5.substring(0, 1)
    val hash2 = md5.substring(0, 2)

    rootUrl + hash1 + "/" + hash2 + "/" + fileName

}
```

Careful about leading zeros, as discussed here:

[Does wikipedia use different methods to compute the hash part of an image path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389616/does-wikipedia-use-different-methods-to-compute-the-hash-part-of-an-image-path)

http://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/mediawiki-api/2011-December/thread.html#2446

Comment: I've heard in #wikimedia IRC that there is no way to predict whether an image is in /commons or /en, so you need to ask the API, or guess and check.